# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index when applying function to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, networkx

i have a custom function which i have to apply to a dataframe. But when I apply the function it gives the above error. The dataframe looks like this:

[image]

The function is:

```
def f(x):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(x, 'restart_A', 'restart_B')
    l = x.apply(lambda n: ','.join(nx.node_connected_component(G, n['restart_A'])), axis=1)
    return l

df_2['subgroup_name'] = df_2.groupby('Group').apply(f).to_numpy()
```

what am I doing wrong? i have also done reset_index which is not visible here

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-01'],
        "restart_A": ['User-1013861701','User-1013861701','User-1013861701'],
        "restart_B": ['User-202955957','User-1744844911','User-5711961755'],
        "Group":['G0', 'G0','G0']
    }
)
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ['2020-07-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-01'],
        "restart_A": ['User-1013861701','User-1013861701','User-1013861701'],
        "restart_B": ['User-202955957','User-1744844911','User-5711961755   '],
        "Group":['G0', 'G0','G0']
    }
)

def f(x):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(x, 'restart_A', 'restart_B')
    l = x.apply(lambda n: ','.join(nx.node_connected_component(G, n['restart_A'])), axis=1)
    x['subgroup_name'] = l.to_numpy()
    return x

df_2 = df_2.groupby('Group').apply(f)

print(df_2)
```

Output:

```
         Date        restart_A           restart_B Group                                      subgroup_name
0  2020-07-01  User-1013861701      User-202955957    G0  User-202955957,User-1013861701,User-5711961755...
1  2020-07-01  User-1013861701     User-1744844911    G0  User-202955957,User-1013861701,User-5711961755...
2  2020-07-01  User-1013861701  User-5711961755       G0  User-202955957,User-1013861701,User-5711961755...
```

Comment: nope not working.. i want to create a new column with that function. it is throwing an error

Comment: @phoenix Updated the full code along with the output. Could you try it again?

Comment: yes now it worked.. can u tell me what was the problem?

Comment: @phoenix It's the same code. There might have been a copy/paste error at your end.

Comment: now thats weird.. because it used to work fine yesterday.. I'm confused lol

Comment: Assuming you have the history on the file, could you paste any difference you see starting from `f(x)` till end of suggestion between the version that worked and the one that didn't?

Comment: @balajji it is the same output.. i cant see any difference.. the code u gave, gives the same output as I used to get before